# Jquery $(document.activeElement).is(':focus') return false ? (in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery

By definition, document.activeElement should return the element with focus, but

```
$(document.activeElement).is(':focus')
```

seems to return false sometimes. (Jquery 1.7.2 is Used)

[exemple in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRQHB/1/)

The first time you display this fiddle, the result is true, then if you click on run button, the result become false.

Edit : This issue can be replicated in Firefox 15 and 10 on ubuntu.

Has someone an explanation on this behavior ?

Comment: I was not able to replicate this issue on Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m.

Comment: I am testing it in Chrome and it's always true.

Comment: What browser are you running jsFiddle in?

Comment: I'm testing in firefox 15.0.1 with ubuntu

Comment: Is the field actually being focused when you observe a `false` result? Does it get the input if you type something? It might be a case of the element not getting the focus at all.

Comment: No, the input isn't really focused, but why is $(document.activeElement).attr('id') return the correct id ? N.B : the problem can be replicated in Firefox 10

Answer (score 0):

It's happening with Firefox just because Firefox doesn't allow focusout and focus at a same time on same element as when we call function focus for some element it call outfocus from previous one.

Now you will think why its showing it as a active element just because reference not changed  solution for you  first call focusout and after that call focus and other operation with set time out.